# Masking methods in R

Tags: r, dplyr, r-package

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600958/using-gather-from-tidyr-changes-my-regression-results/30638813) and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638813/2591234) brought up the following question: How can I get a warning about the masking of methods in R?

If you run the following code in a clean R session, you'll notice that loading `dplyr` changes the default method for `lag`.

```
lag(1:3, 1)
## [1] 1 2 3
## attr(,"tsp")
## [1] 0 2 1
require(dplyr)
lag(1:3, 1)
## [1] NA  1  2
```

If you attach the package `dplyr`, you get warnigns for several masked objects, but no warning about the default method for `lag` being masked. The reason is that when calling `lag`, the generic function from the `stats` package is called.

```
lag
## function (x, ...) 
## UseMethod("lag")
## <bytecode: 0x000000000c072188>
## <environment: namespace:stats>
```

And `methods(lag)` just tells me that there is a method `lag.default`. I can see that there are two methods using `getAnywhere`:

```
getAnywhere(lag.default)
## 2 differing objects matching ‘lag.default’ were found
## in the following places
## registered S3 method for lag from namespace dplyr
## namespace:dplyr
## namespace:stats
## Use [] to view one of them
```

But this requires that I know to check if the default `lag` method was changed by `dplyr`. Is there any way to check if methods were masked? Perhaps there is a function like this:

```
checkMethodMasking(dplyr)
## The following methods are masked from 'package:dplyr':
##    lag.default
```

NB: It is not enough to have a warning when I load `dplyr` with `require(dplyr)`. The method also gets overloaded if I just load the namespace without attaching the package (e.g. I call `dplyr::mutate`, or even I use a function from another package that calls a `dplyr` function that was imported using `importFrom`).

Comment: FWIW dplyr doesn't override that method in the next version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `conflicted` package (see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/conflicted/versions/1.0.4)) now offers a potential solution to this problem. With `conflicted` loaded, you get more explicit error messages about conflicting function names. You also can use `conflict_prefer` (details [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/conflicted/versions/1.0.4/topics/conflict_prefer)) to specify which package's function you want to use by default and which should be masked.

For example, here is a recent error I got when attempting to use the function `parallel` from the `nFactors` package:

```
# Error: [conflicted] `parallel` found in 2 packages.
# Either pick the one you want with `::` 
# * nFactors::parallel
# * lattice::parallel
# Or declare a preference with `conflict_prefer()`
# * conflict_prefer("parallel", "nFactors")
# * conflict_prefer("parallel", "lattice")
```

I then added

```
conflict_prefer("parallel", "nFactors")
```

right after the code loading my libraries at the beginning of the script to make sure that `parallel` would call `nFactors::parallel` in my code.

Answer (score 9):

**Update** There is now an R package on [github](https://github.com/blasern/warnS3) that tries to solve these issues. It is still far from an ideal solution, but it goes som way towards solving the issue. It currently has functions `require`,  `library` and `warnS3Methods`.

```
devtools::install_github("blasern/warnS3")
require(warnS3)

# Examples
require2(dplyr)
## Loading required package: dplyr
##
## Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
##
## The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:
##  
##  filter
##
## The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
##   
##  intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
## 
## The following methods are masked by 'package:dplyr':
##  
##  'lag.default' from 'package:stats'

require2(roxygen2)
## Loading required package: roxygen2
## The following methods are masked by 'package:roxygen2':
##  
##  'escape.character' from 'package:dplyr'

warnS3Methods()
## The following methods are available in multiple packages: 
##  
##  'escape.character' in packages: dplyr, roxygen2
##  'lag.default' in packages: dplyr, stats
```

This is only a an idea of how one can find masked S3 methods. It is by no means a perfect solution, but I guess until somebody comes up with a better idea it will at least help with debuging.

```
#' Get all S3 methods from a package
#' 
#' Find all S3 methods from a package
#' 
#' @param pkg can be either the name of an installed package
#' or the path of a package
getPkgS3Methods <- function(pkg){
  if (basename(pkg) == pkg) pkg <- path.package(pkg)
  ns <- parseNamespaceFile(basename(pkg), 
                           dirname(pkg), 
                           mustExist = FALSE)
  if (length(ns$S3methods) == 0) return(NULL)
  df <- cbind.data.frame(basename(pkg), ns$S3methods)
  colnames(df) <- c("package", "method", "class", "other")
  df
}

#' Get masked S3 methods
#' 
#' Finds all S3 methods that are currently available that are
#' duplicated
getMaskedS3Methods <- function(){
  paths <- as.character(gtools::loadedPackages(silent = TRUE)[, "Path"])
  lst <- lapply(paths, getPkgS3Methods)
  all_methods <- do.call(rbind, lst)
  duplicates <- 
  duplicated(all_methods[, c("method", "class")]) |
    duplicated(all_methods[, c("method", "class")], fromLast = TRUE)
  res <- all_methods[duplicates, ]
  res[order(res$method, res$class, res$package), ]
}
```

Called from a clean workspace (with the above functions, but no packages loaded), you can then observe the following:

```
getMaskedS3Methods()
## [1] package method  class   other  
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

require(dplyr)
getMaskedS3Methods()
## package method   class other
## 143   dplyr    lag default  <NA>
## 438   stats    lag default  <NA>
```

That just tells you that here are two `lag.default` methods. It does not actually tell you, which one is masking the other. It just points out potential problems.

Comment: I really don't undersand why this mess was created, so many issues because of incorporation of conflicting objects names by author of (very good otrherwise) `dplyr` package